# CSV export option for a huge hana table does memory error

Tags: hadoop, out-of-memory, export-to-csv, large-data, hana

Error

> remote export failed: export size exceeds 20% of available memory. please use server-local export

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it already: with HANA Studio the amount of data that one can export is limited.

The solution for mass data export is to use the server-side export/import functions.
Those functions allow reading/writing data from/to directories that are accessible to the user that runs the `hdbindexserver` process (usually that user is called `XXXadm` where `XXX` is your system ID - for a HANA express system that's `hdbadm`)

The syntax and use of the commands are documented [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.05/en-US/20a5342e75191014bb95e83cbbe772fa.html).